# In nested stored procedures - how to safely continue run the calling procedure even if the inner procedure fails?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, nested

I have one scenario, where I have nested stored procedures. I want my main procedure to continue running even if the called procedure (it just have some logging in a table) didn't run successfully.
can you please help.
many thanks!

main Stored Procedure

exec testSP -- Inner SP

-- I want the following code of main SP to run even if the inner SP fails or there is sometime issues or anything that makes it to fail

code for the main SP

Comment: What database are you using ?

Comment: @Squirrel SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use try-catch inside your main stored procedure (and/or your testSP as well).

```
BEGIN TRY
  EXEC testSP
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  -- do something when an error occurs
  SELECT ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_MESSAGE(), 'testSP'
END CATCH
```

Comment: i want to continue with the code of the main Stored procedure even after the error then should i write that code in catch block? to continue?

Comment: @SqlLearner No, if you put the code you want to run in the catch block, it will _only_ run when the inner procedure fails. Just put the code _after_ the catch block. The try/catch handler should be only wrapped around the unit of work that you expect to fail. I suppose you _could_ write it so that after the procedure call you raise an error manually, so that catch is entered whether the procedure succeeds or fails, but this is not going to be intuitive to future maintainers.

Comment: i edit my awnser - for example when an error occurs u can provide error number and error message ... so it's easier to see where there error raised. The main stored procedure will continue after process the catch block

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker Thanks very much, cleared my confusion :)

Comment: BEGIN TRY
  EXEC populate_logfile  SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 5000 -- this sp logs the results.  --Nothing is returned to avoid crashing this process.
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
   SELECT ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_MESSAGE()
  END CATCH

Comment: is this correct way of doing it? i want to timeout after 5 seconds, catch the error and then continue with my following code of main sp. Please suggest , thanks.